# Transpose of C matrix (row-major order)

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

The goal is to get the transpose of the matrix passed in argument.

I did this but don't get what expected:

`m` is the matrix and `r` is where the result is stored

```
void transpose(double m[], size_t rows, size_t cols, double r[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i += 1)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j += 1)
        {
            r[j * cols + i] = m[i * rows + j];
        }
    }
}
```

When I print it, only the first row is transposed and becomes the 1st column.

Example:

```
1 2
3 4
```

will be:

```
1 3
2 4
```

but using my code:

```
1 2
3 4
```

gives me :

```
1 0
2 0
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Did you try this with square matrices and still get only the first row transposed? The error seems to be coming from the single line inside the two `for` loops where you map one serialized matrix to another serialized one, but you are not doing it correctly.

Comment: Yes exactly Motun !! Only the first row is tranposed

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
r[j * cols + i] = m[i * rows + j];
```

is wrong. Try with:

```
r[j * rows + i] = m[i * cols + j];
```

as it is the number of columns that gives the distance between rows.

Comment: Well, it does work for all the matrices I tested, except squared ones

Comment: @whohasfriends2 Not sure what you mean by "... except squared ones". Is it my code you refer to?

Comment: I mean for example 2x2 matrices

Comment: @whohasfriends2 Are you saying that the code in my answer does **not** work for 2x2?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments and as stated in 4386427's answer, your mapping is wrong.

To demonstrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW (2)
#define COLUMN (3)

void transpose(double m[], size_t rows, size_t cols, double r[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i += 1)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j += 1)
        {
            printf("i = %zu, j = %zu --- Interchanging %lf with %lf\n", i, j, r[j * rows + i], m[i * cols + j]);
            r[j * rows + i] = m[i * cols + j];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    double m[ROW*COLUMN] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    double n[COLUMN*ROW] = { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

    /*       
     *  m -> 1 2 3
     *       4 5 6
     * 
     *  n -> 7  8
     *       9  10
     *       11 12
     */

    transpose(m, ROW, COLUMN, n);
    printf("\nTranspose of matrix m is (in 1D form):\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < ROW*COLUMN; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf ", n[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I initialized the second matrix as well, to see which number goes to where.

The output:

```
[root@localhost little_programs]# gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o matrix_T matrix_T.c
[root@localhost little_programs]# ./matrix_T
i = 0, j = 0 --- Interchanging 7.000000 with 1.000000
i = 0, j = 1 --- Interchanging 9.000000 with 2.000000
i = 0, j = 2 --- Interchanging 11.000000 with 3.000000
i = 1, j = 0 --- Interchanging 8.000000 with 4.000000
i = 1, j = 1 --- Interchanging 10.000000 with 5.000000
i = 1, j = 2 --- Interchanging 12.000000 with 6.000000

Transpose of matrix m is (in 1D form):
1.000000 4.000000 2.000000 5.000000 3.000000 6.000000
```

Carefully inspect what is happening in each step of the loops and you will see what went wrong.